# CodeIgniter Validation: using PHP functions

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'd like to use `htmlentities` as part of my CI validation/prepping process. CI says I can use any function that accepts 1 parameter, like htmlentities. However, I actually need to use it this way:

```
htmlentities($foo, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Meaning, I need to pass it flags and an encoding. Is there a way I can make this part of CI validation without trying to create a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extend the form_validation class, and add this as a function - then you can use it globally on all your validations.

```
public function htmlentities($str)
{       
       return htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}
```

And then use it like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required|htmlentities');
```

Comment: I don't really want to override PHP's function or use callbacks. Was hoping to be able to do it in CI's validation rules.

Comment: well there is no htmlentities rule in CI - so you have no choice. Either override Codeigniter (not PHP), or do a callback.